# EVENT API in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle. I'm trying to write an Events API in moodle that will be called when a user logged in and logged out. I have created a local plugin and the directory structure is as follows

os_template/
├── classes  
│     └── observer.php
├── db 
│     └── events.php 
└── version.php

db/events.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname' => '\core\event\user_loggedin',
        'callback' => '\local_ostemplate\local_ostemplateevents::user_loggedin',
    ),
    array(
        'eventname' => '\core\event\user_loggedout',
        'callback' => '\local_ostemplate\local_ostemplateevents::user_loggedin',
    ),
);
```

classes/observer.php

```
namespace local_ostemplate;
class local_ostemplateevents
{
    public static function user_loggedin(core\event\base $event)
    {
        file_put_contents("test.txt","User Logged in");
    }
}
```

But no events are called when user logged in to the moodle. Anybody please help

Comment: Have you logged in as admin and visited the notifications page to trigger the install of the event handlers? If you added the events.php file after you installed the plugin, then you will need to increase the version number and login as admin, before it will pick up the handler. Aside from that, the code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your observer class "local_ostemplateevents" must have the same name as the file it is in, due to the Autoloader.

So change to something like:

os_template/

├── classes

│ └── ostemplateobserver.php

├── db

│ └── events.php

└── version.php

events.php:

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname' => '\core\event\user_loggedin',
        'callback' => '\local_ostemplate\ostemplateobserver::user_loggedin',
    ),
    array(
        'eventname' => '\core\event\user_loggedout',
        'callback' => '\local_ostemplate\ostemplateobserver::user_loggedin',
    ),
);
```

ostemplateobserver.php:

```
namespace local_ostemplate;
class ostemplateobserver {
    public static function user_loggedin(core\event\base $event) {
        file_put_contents("test.txt","User Logged in");
    }
}
```